# List files from a folder to download

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to list files for download on jsp page from a folder. I'm using jsp-servlet combination. I badly need help with this one. Please note - I want to stick to jsp-servlet combination

**Servlet Code**

```
package com.candidjava.servlet.download;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    //String filename = "documents.txt";
    String filepath = "d:\\uploads\\";
```

Comment: You have Java API's `file.listFiles();` and `file.list()`

Comment: Hi Viswanath, could you please elaborate your point?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution on my own on this - pasting code below in case anyone is looking to achieve same thing. Thank you very much!!!

**JSP Code**

```
<%-- 
Document   : ctsDownloadDocuments
Created on : 5 Aug, 2016, 2:18:17 PM
Author     : Admin
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">



</head>

<body>
            <form>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-25">
                                                <div class="panel panel-success" style="width: auto;" >
                                                    <div class="panel-heading" style="width: auto;" >
                                                        <h3 class="panel-title" style="width: auto;"  ><i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i> Case History</h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div style="overflow:scroll;height:400px;width:auto; overflow:auto">
                                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr>


                                                                    <th>FileName</th>

                                                                                                                                        </tr>
                                                            </thead>

                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <c:forEach items="${casedocuments}" var="casedocument">
                                                                    <tr>

                                                                        <td><a href="CaseDocumentController?action=download&FileName=<c:out value="${casedocument.cdd_DocumentName}"/>">Download</a></td>


                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </c:forEach>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>  
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                                                    </form>

                    </div>




</body>
```

**Servlet Code**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

import com.cts.dao.CaseDocumentDAO;
import com.cts.model.CaseDocument;
import com.cts.model.CaseDetail;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class CaseDocumentController extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/ctsCaseDocuments.jsp";
private static String LIST_CASEDETAIL = "/ctsCaseDocuments.jsp";
private static String LIST_CASEDDOCUMENTS = "/ctsDownloadDocuments.jsp";
private CaseDocumentDAO dao;

private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "d:/uploads";

public CaseDocumentController() {
    super();
    dao = new CaseDocumentDAO();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forward = "";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("download")) {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String filename = request.getParameter("FileName");;
    String filepath = "d:\\uploads\\";



    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
            + filename + "\"");

    // use inline if you want to view the content in browser, helpful for
    // pdf file
    // response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=\"" +
    // filename + "\"");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath
            + filename);

    int i;
    while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(i);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();
    out.close();
    }

    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listDocument")) {
                forward = LIST_CASEDETAIL;
                request.setAttribute("casemasters", dao.getAllCaseMaster());
     }

     else
     {
                forward = LIST_CASEDDOCUMENTS;
                request.setAttribute("casemasters", dao.getAllCaseMaster());
                request.setAttribute("casedocuments", dao.getAllCaseDocuments());
     }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}


}
```